# Given a series of dates find the last business day in July in that series for each year

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I have a series of dates, which is an index of a dataframe. I want to identify the last business day in July in that series for every year. So if my series is from 01-01-2017 to 31-12-2022, I should be able to get 6 dates.

The series may not have **all** business days. For instance, if the series does not contain a single day of July in 2021, then I should only get 5 dates. Similarly, if the series only contains 01-07-2021 and no other days in July, then it should give me 01-07-2021.

How do I go about this?

Comment: tell in your dataframe all days are work? If so, then you just need to take the last day of July. Let me know if so, then I'll redo the code.

Answer (score 0):

Made `indexes` in `ind` from '2017-01-01' to '2022-12-31'. Indexes placed in dataframe. On the basis of indexes created a column `'ye'` (on it there will be a grouping). I also dropped the indexes in the dataframe (made a column out of them) so that you can take the last date when grouping.

Next, I filter the dataframe df['index'].dt.month == 7 (selecting rows for July) and [df['index'].dt.dayofweek < 5](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.dayofweek.html) (except Saturday and Sunday). Grouping by years, getting the last rows of values. After I delete a column 'ye' and I reset indexes. And I set the dates again as an index.

```
import pandas as pd

ind = pd.date_range(start='2017-01-01', end='2022-12-31', freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'abc': range(len(ind)), 'ye': ind.year}, index = ind)
df = df.reset_index()
df['index'] = pd.to_datetime(df['index'])

df_new = df[(df['index'].dt.month == 7) & (df['index'].dt.dayofweek < 5)]\
    .groupby('ye').aggregate({'index': ['last'],
                              'abc': ['last']}).reset_index(drop=True)

df_new.columns = df_new.columns.droplevel(1)
df_new = df_new.set_index('index')

print(df_new)
```

Output

```
             abc
index           
2017-07-31   211
2018-07-31   576
2019-07-31   941
2020-07-31  1307
2021-07-30  1671
2022-07-29  2035
```